# move_base node without actual robot?

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d, sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

since i have only laser scanner and trying to show obstacles in a built map via hector_slam/gmapping.

first i tried to use costmap_2d only but i have some problems in there ( [my previous question about it](http://answers.ros.org/question/238150/static-map-and-costmap-unmatch/) ) , [and this too](http://answers.ros.org/question/237991/footprint-doesnt-move-in-the-costmap/) so at the same time i want to try move_base launch to see costmap in it with help of amcl...

is this possible to use move_base without having an actual robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238258/move_base-node-without-actual-robot?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it will just send motion commands into nothing, and then probably go into some failures, etc. when nothing moves, so it's a bit pointless. If you are interested only in the costmap, you can just can a costmap ROS instance.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-28**:
cuz of my trial in costmap_2d only has some problems (link in the question) so i think maybe amcl can solve my problem. if the failures are just about move goal or sth like that its ok for me. i just want to manage to see some costmap succesfully

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-06-29**:
For the costmap, just a CostMap instance is sufficient. Complete move_base should also work and fail to execute, etc.. This makes mostly sense as preparation if you plan to execute something at some point in time.

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-29**:
just want to see obstacles so yes costmap is the only thing i need but, didnt manage it :/ cuz static map from mapserver and costmap itself isnt match (i think its because lack of localization) anyway thanks, i'm trying the both (costmap only and move_base) i hope i can solve that unmatching problem